# Shared config file for both Angular and Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, node-modules

I want to create a simple config file with one object, for example:

```
const config = {
    serverIp: "localhost",
    serverPort: 3000
}
```

which I can use in both Angular (Angular-cli with typescript):

```
import { config } from '../pathToConfigFile';
```

and node.js server (javascript):

```
const config = require("./config");
```

If I do this (config has .js extension):

```
export const config = {
    ipOrDomainName: "localhost",
    serverPort: 3000
}

if(module && module.exports){
    module.exports = config;
}
```

I get this error on server

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

And in typescript I get this error

> Module '../../../../../config.js' was resolved to
>   'C:/Users/(...)/config.js', but '--allowJs'
>   is not set.

How can I get this module to be working in both Angular and node?

Comment: Why do you want to share the same? the one for node.js will be on the server side ? And you have a syntax error in the file on if(...) line

Comment: I am using socket.io, and in development mode I need to use
"private client = io('localhost:3000');" on client side (client port is 4200, server's is 3000), so I thought it would be better to change the server IP and port in only one file, instead of searching in Angular service files, and then changing it again in server file.

Comment: Your file has .js extention? Are you sure you can do import {} from js?

Comment: Config file has .js extension. Imports are part of ES6, but aren't supported in node.js.